# How do I customize the CSS of just my FIRST post on archive/home pages?

Tags: css, blogger

So I've done a lot of research before asking this question. I already know how to use the if/else and conditional tags to make certain code applicable to only certain pages, BUT, I noticed that there isn't a single guide or question-answer out there addressing my question on only styling the first/most recent post in my blogger.
The closest I got to finding the solution (other than codes that I didn't have the skill to implement), was this one: http://helplogger.blogspot.ro/2014/01/create-magazine-style-layout-for-blogger-posts.html

Sample site from that tutorial: http://helploggertestblog.blogspot.com/

The problem with the above script is that was made to be too automated, and I don't need a post-summary or thumbnail for my other posts-- I'm only trying to change the look for the first post. I love that the first post's width was increased, bordered, color-changed, and what not.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might isolate what I'm looking for, point me towards the right direction, or even hand me a general container so that I can get on with my life?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing any of your code it's kinda guessing, but I'll give it a try anyway.

I'm guessing that you have the posts in a `div` or other parent element. Something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Content of the post ... </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Content of the post ... </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Content of the post ... </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

To style only the first div inside the container, you can use:

```
.container > div:nth-first-child {
   /* your specific style here */
}
```

With your code, it would be easier to help...

**EDIT**
Use:

```
.blog-posts > .post-outer:first-child {
     background: green;
}
```

Comment: To be a bit more specific on the code, I'm actually using a modified version of the "Simple Template" from blogger, so it's a pretty standardized template.

I keep hearing about replacing the "<b:include data='post' name='post'/>" part of my template with a different kind of code to separately place the posts, but I'm not sure how to get started.

Comment: I just tried out your code, and it's amazing that I actually found a solution to my dilemma! I just have one more quick question: How might I use the container to adjust smaller things INSIDE of the container? What I mean is something like this: .blog-posts > .post-outer:first-child {
.post-body img {
max-width:230px;
max-height:auto;
}
}

Or is something like that OUTSIDE of the container that you provided? I'm looking to change things like the position of categories, post titles, and images on only my first post. Of course you've been a giant help, and I appreciate everything you've done.

Comment: Regardless if you have the time to reply, I'm going to go ahead and credit you for your help when I push everything to a final copy. You're a great help!

Comment: To clarify, I've already used things like, "color: #f3f3f3;" and small text modifers to mix things up on the first post, but the individual elements are really the things that distinguish the first post (stackoverflow wouldn't let me edit my topic after 5 minutes).

Comment: If you indent your code, like I did for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/K9ADf/ You can see better how the hierarchy is. So if you want to target the image, you use `.blog-posts > .post-outer:first-child .post-body img { ... }` or if you want to change the category `.blog-posts > .post-outer:first-child .post-labels a { ... }`, and so on... If the answer satisfies your needs, please mark it as answer (the v mark of the left of it).

Answer (score 0):

There is a conditional tag available for 1st post

```
<b:if cond='data:post.isFirstPost'> 
Your custom css only for the 1st post here
</b:if>
```

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that conditional on multiple snippets about conditional values, but that conditional actually applies to everything BELOW the first post. I figured that out after I saw a bunch of codes use that condition to put ads under their posts.